# Microsoft safelinks

Tags: asp.net

I have a site that sends links to users. When they click the link they are forwarded another email which is a simple thing to execute. I now have a problem that when I send those links to users, Microsoft's safelink feature will hit that link multiple times and the user will receive the same email multiple times. Is there a work around so that the email is only sent out once without removing the safelink?
I'm using ASP.NET MVC

Comment: You could track in your data if the message has already been sent and not re-send it.  Perhaps include a button in the UI for that link's page where the user can manually request a re-send if they need it again.  (Note that sending an email or performing some other data-persistent operation on a GET request is highly unusual, so there's always the option of re-thinking the logic flow for what you're doing anyway.)

Comment: Make it so they have to click a button on the first link in order to get the second email. (rethinking the logic as @David suggested).

Answer (score 2):

Frame challenge: Don't make a link (`HTTP GET`) cause an action (such as sending a mail).

Let me [quote Oded from a related question on Software Engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/188861/33843):

> A GET is defined in this way in the HTTP protocol. It is supposed to be idempotent and safe.
>
> As for why - a GET can be cached and in a browser, refreshed. Over and over and over.
>
> [...]
>
> Consider what this may mean if the GET becomes a link and it gets crawled by a search engine. [...]
>
> [...]
>
> There is also a problem with link prefetching in some browsers - they will make a call to pre-fetch links, even if not indicated so by the page author.

Make the link show a page. On this page, but a *button* (`HTTP POST`) which causes the desired action (such as sending an e-mail) to occur.

Comment: This was my original idea but its required that it be a link of sort so that people only have to interreact with what comes to the email and nothing else. I did try adding sending a form with the email that made a post to send those emails which worked to some extent. If I vew the emails in web-browser it works fine but if viewed on outlook app or mail app on windows then outlook strips away the entire form and replaces it with <p> tags. Any advice on this?